# Receiving "NAudio.MmException: NoDriver calling acmFormatSuggest" Exception on WAV File

Tags: c#, naudio

When I run this line of code on a Wav file:

AudioFileReader1 = New AudioFileReader(Me.FilePath)

I get this error:

NAudio.MmException: NoDriver calling acmFormatSuggest at NAudio.Wave.Compression.AcmStream.SuggestPcmFormat(WaveFormat compressedFormat) at NAudio.Wave.WaveFormatConversionStream.CreatePcmStream(WaveStream sourceStream)    at NAudio.Wave.AudioFileReader.CreateReaderStream(String fileName)   at NAudio.Wave.AudioFileReader..ctor(String fileName)

I've found a number of references to solve this problem for an mp3 file, but none for a Wav file.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

This means that there is no ACM codec installed on your machine that is able to decode the `WaveFormat` of the WAV file. If you open it with a `WaveFileReader` and look at the `WaveFormat` property you will be able to see what compression type is being used